# How to pass forms event to a parent component to preventDefault?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I have a quite standard form:

```
export default class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      refCode: ''
    }
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    this.changeEmail = this.changeEmail.bind(this)
  }

  changeEmail (event) {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value })
  }

  onSubmit () {
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.props.title}</h2>
        <form className={cx('Form')} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input
            className={cx('Form-email')}
            onChange={this.changeEmail}
            value={this.state.email}
            type='email'
            placeholder='email' />
          <input className={cx('Form-refcode')} type='text' placeholder='enter referal code' />
          <input className={cx('Form-btn')} type='submit' value='sign up' />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I then want to handle forms submission in a parent component, via this function

```
submitForm (value) {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log(value.email)
}

/* ... */

<Form
  title='What are you waiting for?! Sign up now'
  onSubmit={this.submitForm} />
```

The issue I encountered is that `event.preventDefault()` is not working, nor does it seem that I am getting correct value logged via console.

I assume I am not passing or receiving values here correctly but I have no idea where i'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In child component pass `event`(you can name it as you want) argument to method from parent component

```
onSubmit (event) {
  this.props.onSubmit(event, this.state)
}
```

In parent component do like this

```
submitForm (event, value) {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.log(value.email)
}
```